# How to Upgrade MQ with incremental approach with 50 micro services

Tags: java, architecture, microservices, upgrade, amqp

I have around 50 microservices which communicate with each other using Apache MQ implementation.

I want to know if I can avoid big bang approach when I need to upgrade the MQ version.

Current option that I can think of is put a switch in each micro service and then on the D  day we switch on the new MQ.
But this is a big bang approach.
I want to know if there can be other way to perform this kind of middle ware upgrade.